# CATIA V5 parameter and macro

Tags: vba, catia

I am working on an assignment for my studies on CATIA but I'm new on it. In fact, I am working on a parametric design and I wan't to limit a parameter from an other value.

I created a boolean formula which return false when the value that I have prompted is too big.It works well but when I prompt the value the sketch change over the limit...
Here the problem
[image: Here the problem]

You can see in the picture WT: wall thickness, that's the value I have to prompt and ThicknessLimitation is the boolean formula which return false if WT is over the limits.

What I want avoid
[image: What I want avoid]

If you have any idea how can I set these features...

Thanks you

Comment: How do you want to change your parameters? via a macro? Have you considered to use a KWA Rule or Check in Catia?